# MVC: Controller or Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm very new to MVC, and I would like to get a clarification about the function of a controller.

Imagine this primitive example:

I have **2 models** and **1 controller**, that gets data from both models, and I have to do a very complicated calculation with these 2 data packages. (Then give the result to a view.)

My question is:

Should I put this complicated calculation **into the controller**, **or** should I put it outside **into a library**? 
In more general form:

Am I allowed to make calculations inside a controller, or is it a bad practice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735466/fat-model-thin-controller-vs-service-layer

Comment: Model is **one**. It is a layer not a class.

Comment: @tereško how do you mean it? I use php, and everywhere I saw the implementation of mvc, models were classes.

Comment: @BalazsSipos , only type of frameworks which refer to "models" as classes are Rails clones. And it was never an MVC framework to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are the easy place to put this kind of logic, and become easily cluttered.  Separation of concerns would take you down the path of implementing a [service layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702391/mvcs-model-view-controller-service).

Answer (score 0):

`Controllers` should be as light as possible and have few dependencies.  Your `Model` should handle business logic like this although you may want to put it in its own library.  If you do put it in a different library, call it from the `model`.