# IEumerable<> in a MVC ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, mvvm, viewmodel

I've been trying to get a better grasp on Model and ViewModel design.  And for most of you out there, this is probably a silly question.  For starters, here is my model:

```
public class Cities
{
    [Key]
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Miles { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I create my ViewModel within my presentation layer, can I just use IEumerable<> to pass all records within my Cities table:

```
public class CitiesViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Cities> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

And then I could loop through all records with my Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        CitiesViewModel model = new CitiesViewModel
        {
            Cities = repository.Cities
            .OrderBy(p => p.City)
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Or, should I just pass in the only data I want my View to have access to:

```
public class CitiesViewModel
{
    //public IEnumerable<Cities> Cities { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Check [one.beat.consumer's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735466/fat-model-thin-controller-vs-service-layer), it should give you an idea.

Comment: I think the purists would argue that the latter is the better choice, but I find both acceptable.

Comment: Yeah, view models are supposed to provide only the information needed by the view.

Comment: @MarcosVqzdeRdz Thanks for the reference.  Great info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
class CityViewModel
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State{ get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
class CitiesViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CityViewModel> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I actually prefer to bind the `IEnumerable<>` to the view rather than creating a class that only holds a collection of the first viewmodel. e.g. `@model IEnumerable<CityViewModel>`

Comment: Me too, but Im not sure if thats the only information needed in the view.

Answer (score 0):

That depends of what do you want display on your view. If details of one City use :

```
public class CitiesViewModel
{


    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

but if you want to display list of cites use :

```
public class CitiesViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Cities> Cities { get; set; }
}
```